# PHP redirect from server

Tags: php, redirect

I have two php files. In the first file I am fetching all the user input details and in the other php file, all the validations and mail sending is happening. Its just a webhook not accessible through the browser so cannot use Javascript or html meta tags for the redirection. The main problem I am facing here is, want to send the header with 200 to the server which is calling the webhook before the redirection.

using following code for redirection,

```
header("Location: http://example/mailsend.php");
```

but it's waiting till the execution of eof. is there any way to return the header with HTTP status code first and continue the redirection?

Also tried, `ob_start()` and `flush()` but no luck.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean by *"return the header with HTTP status code first and continue the redirection"*.  A redirect *is* an HTTP status code response.

Comment: Yes! but like i said, it is waiting until the entire process is getting completed. it is taking more than 13secs to return any status code.

Comment: If you just want to cancel the server-side code then you could use `die;` or `return;` at the top level of the PHP script.

Comment: use CURL to return just the header?

Comment: Can i use use something like this? header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');
header("Location: http://example/mailsend.php");